# Update object after saving it

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save the list of `persons`, once saved, again update it and save it like below:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

persons.forEach(person-> em.persist(person));
em.flush();
```

Now I need to update each `person` object and then again save it to the database:

```
persons.forEach(person-> {
// set some field in person
     em.merge(person)
});
```

I am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "preson_depend" violates foreign key constraint "fk_person_depend
_person"
  Detail: Key (person_id)=(37) is not present in table "another_person".
```

I do not get exception if I do not update it after persisting it.

Comment: Could you show us the code for the `Person` object and the structure of the table (particularly that foreign key) ?

Comment: I have got it, my joint table was referring some other table which was not needed, I have removed that fk and it worked, you comments hit me :) thanks